# MS Word: 'Expand/collapse all headings' options missing from right-click menu

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using collapsible headings in Word. The right-click menu for these headings includes a sub-menu with unique options for 'Expand/collapse all headings'.

In *one* of my documents, this sub-menu is missing. In its place, the right-click menu shows three options related to list indents (although this may be incidental). Without the sub-menu I cannot expand or collapse headings without clicking on each one separately, which is very frustrating.

This particular document must have an option *somewhere* which causes the sub-menu to appear or disappear, or which causes the list indent options to replace it. But I can't find any such option. Any ideas?

(P.S. This isn't fixed by the 'Collapsed by default' checkbox in the 'Paragraph' window; that's for something else.)

Comment: You should post this document online if you want us to have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this yet?

To add the "Expand/Collapse All Headings" option to the context menu in Microsoft Word, you will need to customize the Quick Access Toolbar by following these steps:

1. Click on the arrow next to the Quick Access Toolbar and select "More Commands..." at the bottom of the list.
2. In the "Word Options" dialog box, click on "Customize Ribbon" on the left-hand side.
3. Under the "Customize the Ribbon" section, click on "Customize..." next to "Quick Access Toolbar".
4. In the "Choose commands from:" dropdown, select "All Commands".
5. Scroll down and select "Expand/Collapse All Headings".
6. Click the "Add" button to add it to the Quick Access Toolbar.
7. Click "OK" to close the "Word Options" dialog box.

Now when you right-click on a heading in your document, you should see the option to "Expand/Collapse All Headings" in the context menu.

Comment: Thanks, this has worked and is just as good. Strange that the options are missing from the right-click menu though.

Comment: You're welcome! :) It would help me if you could also upvote the answer.

Comment: I would, but, I just signed up and I can't upvote answers unless I get more credits or whatever. Seems pretty pointless to me but that's how it works apparently :S

Comment: Ah, right. I forgot about this. It seems you need at least 15 reputation to be able to upvote. You can try to fix the grammar mistakes on the latest published threads to get +2 points if your edit/s get/s approved. Although, I'm not sure if you have edit privileges. Thanks for trying! :)